# Start PC Ubuntu With Keyboard

Tags: hardware

Is there a way to start a PC with Ubuntu from the Keyboard?
Because my button "Power" is broken.

Comment: Not specific to Ubuntu, but something here may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789171/turn-on-pc-with-usb-device and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684013/wake-up-pc-on-usb

Comment: The power button of a computer case has more functions that just powering the system on (like shutting it down hard if you press it longer than 4 seconds). If we are talking about a regular computer case, a quick fix can be to rewire the reset button to the power button if there is any. In the long term the button or the entire case should be replaced. I don't see however how this could be related to Ubuntu or this site here, contact the customer support if it is still under warranty or go to your next computer store for repair or buy a new case online.

Comment: **vote to close:** This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping for replacement parts, getting your problem fixed in a local computer store or contact customer support for the hardware. It isn't related to software or Ubuntu in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Your power switch is a hardware switch: Simply put, you have to close the open circuit.

To do this, insert a wire at both ends of the switch base or button, then from then on you can keep your system in sleep or hibernation.  Also, see if you can go into the system settings (BIOS) and set up your Wake-on-LAN.

That will allow you to wake up your sleeping system remotely.

Comment: OK,thanks Fernando,but there isn't a Way to Start from keyboard ?
Beacuse start from Wake on Lan is so difficult for me.

Comment: @DavidLanceMarimin: no, not with a completely broken switch